# How to fix error "ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1)."

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working with ionic and my `ionic serve` usually run just fine. Now i want to run an old project but `ionic serve` throws error, showing below error

> [ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's fine now it was my node-sass
just did this "npm uninstall node-sass" "npm install node-sass" "npm rebuild node-sass"

Answer (score 0):

I solve it!
*You must have the lastest version of Node.js and Npm available hr[Here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)
*Run: npm cache clean --force
*Run: npm uninstall -g ionic
*npm install -g @ionic/cli

Answer (score 0):

1)First Remove the Node_modules .
2)next Remove the package-lock.json .
3)then run the Comment `npm i or npm install` .